# Automatically Webscrape Bloominberg

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Is there a way to use Beautiful soup  to automatically search bloomingburg from a list of stocks [T, APPL, PBCT, MSFT]? For instance if you look at this link https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/T:US, this is the T stock chart in bloominberg, I  extract the PEGY ratio, then return in a CVS file. Anyone that has a solution or could help start me in the right direction would be helpful.

This is a starting skeleton I have in pycharm.

```
import bs4
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv



#with open("tickers.txt") as f:
    #stocks = f.read().splitlines()

stocks = ['T', 'PBCT', 'MSFT', 'AAPL']

for link in stocks:
    url = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/' + link + ':US'
    print(url)
    uClient = urlopen(Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'}))
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
    PEGY = page_soup.findAll("span",{"class":"fieldValue__2d582aa7"})
    print(PEGY)
```

output: It appears to be looping through the correct websites, but not scraping the PEGY.

```
https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/T:US
[]
https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/PBCT:US
[]
https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/MSFT:US
[]
https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/AAPL:US
[]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Hi Chad Highfill, welcome to SO. It appears you are not checking the response status code, nor the content-type, of the response and just _assuming_ it is 200 OK and `text/html`, made worse by the fact that you are using what is very clearly not a legal User-Agent. Start by checking the response status code, and writing out `page_html` to a local file, and ensure you can actually see the `fieldValue__2d582aa7` in the response. Good luck!

Comment: Hi mdaniel, thanks you for the response. There is alot for me to unpack here. I am no where as smart as you. Can you break all that down for a simpleton lol. I got the legau user agent. I found that off other sites, so used it.

Comment: [`assert uClient.getcode() == 200`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen), `fh = open("page.html", "w"); fh.write(page_html); fh.close()`, `assert "fieldValue__2d582aa7" in page_html`, and I checked your page and you're going to need a more specific selector since **all** of those `<span>` tags have a class of `fieldValue__2d582aa7`, not just PEGY Ratio. As for the User-Agent, you're welcome to keep using it, but I'm telling you it's wrong, and it's going to make your job harder

Comment: Hi mdaniel, I will be looking into this in detail. I am not an expert and learning from the community. Thanks. If you have an example on a good stock scrapping tool that would improve mine, I would be happy to accept the answer. cheers

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=site%3Agithub.com+bloomberg+scrapy&ia=web